# SQL Server - Multiple developer working on same database causing problems like slow response or no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are working on a table which has more than 20 million of data. I was updating some data with a transaction, but before rollback or commit, I just wanted to verify things are okay. In the meantime, my colleague was trying to get some data from the same table but was getting very slow response. As soon as I commit/rollback my transaction everything becomes normal. What could be the reason and how to solve this. I know when a transaction open, but not committed or rollback it goes to the locked state. Instead of working on two different table by both of us by creating a copy of the table is there a way to solve the issue?

begin transaction
 update table
 -- some other sql code
--no commit/rollback

Comment: Why not simply have each one its own DB engine on his local machine and have a private copy of the database? Use a central server for deploying a test instance or for production, but never for development.

Comment: @Alejandro, frankly I find this a bad idea because you need to know how your changes are affecting other changes in progress and private databases tend to only have a small sample of the records causing a host of other problems including writing code that is found to perform badly when pushed to prod. This might work with small toy database but not large enterprise databases. Further, in no way do you want your business data on a laptop that might get stolen from your house or car.  Nor do developer laptops or workstations generally have the space for large production size databases.

Comment: It's kind of a cleaning process and we wanted to see the changes other people doing. Cleaning million of data with two different tables and merge back together might be slower than how we working now. @Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at transaction isolation levels. Maybe it is acceptable for him to `READ UNCOMMITTED` while you are working on the data? You'll need to ask yourself whether or not it is acceptable for him to potentially be reading "old" data though.

Answer (score 1):

Never write code like that that has an open transaction and then no closure. Sooner or later you will will wander off or go home leaving the table locked.

If you want to see results, write teh code to run in test mode. See below:

```
Declare @test int=1 --0=commit,1=rollback

BEGIN TRY

Begin Transaction



select * from mytable where myfield = 1
update m
set myfield2 = 'test'
from mytable m
where myfield = 1

select * from mytable where myfield = 1


if @test=0
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE IF @test=1
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    Print 'Test-mode, Rolling back'
END

END TRY
Begin catch

SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_MESSAGE()

Rollback transaction

END Catch
```

Now you can see the results in test mode but the transaction is not held open while you go get a cup of coffee. Then when you think they are correct, you can change the @test variable to 0 and run the changes with a commit. If you are going to affect a large number of records, you might change the update code to affect only a sample of the records for testing rather than rollback 10,000,000 records. The remove the code that get the sample for the final.

If your colleague is doing a select, he can use table hints or set Transaction isolation levels to work around the lock. But he should be aware that he may not see the data correctly if he is looking at the same records you are changing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Comment: Great! Will do this from now on. Transaction isolation is the one we are looking for I guess! :)